# Create table inside loop in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to see how to store all my info in one table so i can print it at the end of the loop, here is the code I'm using

```
 trips = 1000   
f1 = 0
f2 = 0
c1 = 18
c2= 12

 #Incremental with proportional factors
 factors = c(0,.35,0.25,0.20,.15,.05)
 n = 6
 for(i in 1:n)
 {
   if(c2 < c1)
   {
     increment = trips * factors[i]
     f2 = f2 + increment
     c2 = 12 + (.01*f2)     
    }
   else
  {
    increment = trips * factors[i]
    f1 = f1 + increment
    c1 = 18 + (.005*f1)
  }
  IncrementalTable = c(i - 1,increment,f2,c2,f1,c1)

}
```

I'd like to store each iteration in the IncrementalTable variable, at the moment i only know how to store one iteration at the time. How do i store it as a table to preserve all the iterations?

something like this

```
Incremental Table =    N  I    F2   C2    F1   C2
                       0  0    0    12    0    18
                       1 350   350  15.5  0    18.0
                       2 250   600  18    0    18
                       3 200   600  18    200  19
                       4 150   750  19.5  200  19
                       5 50    750  19.50 250  19.25
```

Comment: There are nicer ways to do this than a `for` loop. Is the `for` loop of critical importance?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are doing. You don't specify `c1` & `c2` at the top, so the first pass through the loop will be problematic. Also, note that you are wiping out your previous version of `IncrementalTable` on each successive pass through the loop. Can you include what you want the output to look like, in addition?

Comment: No, but i know the for loop so I'm using that. Let me edit the script text to include all the variables.

Comment: I understand your problem better and a loop seems the easiest way. Check out `rbind` to figure out how to record each row. However, try to pre-allocate your final `data.frame` and update rows in each iteration, rather than inserting new rows.

Comment: Im still not sure how to approach it. is there an example that you could provide?

Comment: Adding the variable first as a null before the loop then populating the variable inside the loop will format the table to look as desired.

    #BEFORE LOOP
    IncrementalTable = NULL

    #INSIDELOOP
    IncrementalTable = rbind(IncrementalTable, data.frame(i - 1,increment,f2,c2,f1,c1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get your answer is to set

```
IncrementalTable<-c()
```

at the top of your loop, and then replace the last line of your loop with this:

```
IncrementalTable <- rbind(IncrementalTable,c(i - 1,increment,f2,c2,f1,c1))
```

The result:

```
> IncrementalTable
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]  [,6]
[1,]    0    0  750 19.5  250 19.25
[2,]    1  350  750 19.5  600 21.00
[3,]    2  250 1000 22.0  600 21.00
[4,]    3  200 1000 22.0  800 22.00
[5,]    4  150 1000 22.0  950 22.75
[6,]    5   50 1050 22.5  950 22.75
```

This will give you a plain matrix.  You can then use

```
colnames(IncrementalTable)<-c("R","I","F2","C2","F1","C2")
```

to get the column names you want.

Comment: I did something similar by decleraing a variable as null before the loop and then in the loop using rbind() and data.frame and  colnames() to change my headings.

SAT = NULL

Inside loop:

SAT = rbind(SAT, data.frame(i,phi,f2,c2,f1,c1))